# How to restrict the value in html.textbox for time format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

I need to  restrict the value in html.textbox for time format (00:00:00) [hh:mm:ss) using jquery . restricted values are: special Char , a-z , A-Z all others. Only allowed numbers. ":" values are should be default.

Comment: try this plugin http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html

Comment: But here missing sec and i need 24hr format

Comment: set the `showSeconds` option to true to enable seconds display and show24Hours option to true to enable 24 hr format. `$('time_input').timeEntry({show24Hours: true, showSeconds: true});`

Comment: Have a look at their reference page for more options `http://keith-wood.name/timeEntryRef.html`

Comment: HOw to download script?

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/zip/jquery.timeentry.package-1.5.0.zip

Answer (score 0):

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/b9Arm/
**HTML**

```
<input maxlength="8" type="text" id="time" style="border: 1px solid" />
```

**JS**

```
$('#time').keypress(function(e) {
    if (!((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || 
          (e.shiftKey === true && e.keyCode === 58))) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Note: Other than 48 to 57, also add the keycodes for numbers entered from the numeric keypad. Additionally, you'll need some validation to ensure that the format is indeed dd:dd:dd.

For example:

```
$('#time').blur(function (e) {
    if(!(/\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d/.test($('#time').val()))) {
        alert('Achtung Baby!')
    }
});
```

Comment: how to set the : inbetween gap

Comment: I need to put the ":" value  example (00:00:00)

Comment: Ah, it's going to be complex. Fixed placeholders, like the : separator, can be inserted automatically as the user types, but it opens a whole can of worms, especially when the user deletes stuff. Either use three separate two-digit text fields, with the : set in HTML e.g. <input1> : <input2> : <input3>, or just allow the user to type the : and validate accordingly. You could also use a backgrond image with :  : burned in, but that severely limits font-resizing.

Comment: k . I try my level best . Thank you very much refactor

Answer (score 0):

Click Here http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html ,to know about jquery time entry in textbox html